# Error: Call to a member function getFieldValue() on bool in vendor/magento/framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php:134

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I was getting this error when sending response to the get type ajax controller.

the code was like below.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Download implements HttpGetActionInterface
{


    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $serializer;

    protected $logger;

    protected $http;

    public function __construct(
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Json $json,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Http $http
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->serializer = $json;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->http = $http;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            return $this->jsonResponse('your response');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function jsonResponse($response = '')
    {
        $this->http->getHeaders()->clearHeaders();
        $this->http->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $this->http->setBody(
            $this->serializer->serialize($response)
        );
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple if you look at the Kernel.php line : 134,

you'll find a condition like `$response->getHeader('Cache-Control')->getFieldValue()`
.

So you can set it manually like below,in the response code and the error will be resolved.

```
$this->http->setHeader('Cache-Control', '');
```